# The class "turtles" has no attribute "forward" (Python Turtle)

Tags: python, inheritance, python-turtle

I am trying to make a turtle race, but I get an error that the class "turtles" has no attribute "forward". Here is my code:

```
class turtles:   
    def __init__(self, color, posX):
        self = turtle.Turtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.shape('turtle')
        self.goto(posX, -300)
        self.showturtle()
        self.setheading(90)
    def start_race(self):
        self.forward(random.randrange(0,10))

t1 = turtles('red',-150)
t2 = turtles('orange', -100)
t3 = turtles('yellow',-50)
t4 = turtles('green', 0)
t5 = turtles('light blue', 50)
t6 = turtles('blue',100)
t7 = turtles('purple', 150)

def begin_race():
    t1.start_race()
    t2.start_race()
    t3.start_race()
    t4.start_race()
    t5.start_race()
    t6.start_race()
    t7.start_race()

begin_race()
```

Comment: Dont use self as a variable name. its probably clashing with class definitions.

Comment: `self = ...` is not how inheritance works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `turtles` class with this:

```
class turtles(turtle.Turtle):   
    def __init__(self, color, posX):
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.shape('turtle')
        self.goto(posX, -300)
        self.showturtle()
        self.setheading(90)
    def start_race(self):
        self.forward(random.randrange(0,10))
```

Inheritance in Python is done by specifying a class in brackets after declaring a class name.
In this case, your `turtles` class inherits from the `turtle.Turtle` class and then has its attributes changed. Seems there was also some repetition with specifying the turtle's colour and visibility (I removed that for you)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is because there is no attribute (i.e. a variable or method) called `forward` in your `turtles` class. The `forward` method is part of the `turtle.Turtle` class. You could solve this in different ways:

**Method 1: using inheritance**

You could derive your `turtles` class from the existing `turtle.Turtle` class. To do that, you should make the following changes:

- The class `turtles` should be defined as `class turtles(turtle.Turtle)` to derive from it.
- In the `__init__()` method you should not reassign `self`, because this is a reference to the actual object that's being initialized.
- You should call the `__init__()` method of the original `Turtle` class.

So the full code could be like below. I renamed `start_race()` to `advance_race()` because that better describes what it does. And I added an infinite loop so you'll see the turtles "racing". This is just for demonstration, of course.

```py
import random
import turtle

class turtles(turtle.Turtle):

    def __init__(self, color, posX):
        super().__init__(shape='turtle', visible=False)
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(posX, -300)
        self.showturtle()
        self.setheading(90)

    def advance_race(self):
        self.forward(random.randrange(0,10))

t1 = turtles('red', -150)
t2 = turtles('orange', -100)
t3 = turtles('yellow', -50)
t4 = turtles('green', 0)
t5 = turtles('light blue', 50)
t6 = turtles('blue', 100)
t7 = turtles('purple', 150)

while True:
    t1.advance_race()
    t2.advance_race()
    t3.advance_race()
    t4.advance_race()
    t5.advance_race()
    t6.advance_race()
    t7.advance_race()
```

**Method 2: using a wrapper class**

Alternatively, you could create a new class that "holds" a turtle object. Using this method, you should store the turtle "inside" `self` and access it as `self.turtle` (or any other name).

```py
class turtles:

    def __init__(self, color, posX):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
        self.turtle.color(color)
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(posX, -300)
        self.turtle.showturtle()
        self.turtle.setheading(90)

    def advance_race(self):
        self.turtle.forward(random.randrange(0,10))
```

(rest of the code same as above)